# creating new object json objects in powershell

Tags: json, powershell

I'm trying to create a new object in my json file using powershell and its not working the way I thought it would. The code I made is as follows

Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

The Code I Used:

```
$jsonfile = "C:\Users\Public\add.json"

$json = Get-Content $jsonfile | Out-String | ConvertFrom-Json
foreach($user in $json.test){
    $json.test | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name 'yikes' -Value 'if this works'
    $json | ConvertTo-Json | Set-Content $jsonfile
}
```

The file comes out like this:

```
{
    "test":  [
     
                {
                    "displayName": "hello"
                     "exceptionName":"hello"
                    "idk":  "anymore",
                     "yikes":  "if this works"
                 }
             ],

}
```

What I was expecting:

```
{
    "test":  [
     
                {
                    "displayName": "hello"
                     "exceptionName":"hello"
                 },
                {
                    "idk":  "anymore",
                     "yikes":  "if this works"

                }
             ],

}
```

Comment: What is in ```\add.json```, and why would you think it would come out the way you are showing as your final goal?

Comment: Your source XML syntax isn't right. There is a missing comma after `displayName`.... unnecessary comma after last square bracket. Problem is "ConvertTo-JSON" wont work if you're not feeding proper JSON. After fixing your XML and running your code, I got your expected output.

Comment: If you dont add how the original Json looks it's hard to help you. The clear issue is that you're using `$json` inside your loop when you should be using `$user`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to iterate over the `test` array, You can simply add an object to it:

```
$jsonfile = "C:\Users\Public\add.json"
$json = Get-Content $jsonfile | ConvertFrom-Json
$json.test += @(
    @{
        "idk"   = "anymore"
        "yikes" = "if this works"
    }
)
$json | ConvertTo-Json | Set-Content $jsonfile
```

Comment: that helps a lot. The only thing is it overwrites the whole file still. I still need it be in the test object. This is what it looks like after running it
```{
    "idk":  "anymore",
    "yikes":  "if this works"
}```